# Are Complex Valued $p$ norms possible?

Tags: complex-analysis, normed-spaces

I currently in the midst of a calculation and during this calculation I ran into the question as to whether or not there existed $p$-norms that included $p \in \mathbb{C}$. I know that a $p$-norm is defined as $$||\overrightarrow{x}||_p := \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} |x_{k}|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}$$ for $p \geq 1$. This is because only these values of $p$ satisfy the requirements for being a norm, in that:

1. $||\overrightarrow{x}+\overrightarrow{y}||_p \leq ||\overrightarrow{x}||_p +||\overrightarrow{y} ||_p$
   (Triangle Inequality)
2. $||c \cdot \overrightarrow{x}||_p = |c| \cdot ||\overrightarrow{x}||_p$ (Absolutely Homogeneous)
3. If $||\overrightarrow{x}||_p = 0$, then $\overrightarrow{x} = \overrightarrow{0}$ (Positive Definite)

Despite these criteria, there do exist certain looser "norms", such as semi-norms, the zero norm or $p$ norms with values in the range $(0, 1)$. I'm merely curious if such a "pseudo-norm" exists for complex values of $p$.

Comment: The only definite problem that I see is the triangle inequality not holding for complex values, since the complex numbers are not totally ordered. If there is some subset $P\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that for all $p\in P$ the value of the norm is real and the triangle inequality holds, then you *might* be able to satisfy the other two requirements. You could also *define* an order on the complex numbers so that the 1. makes sense.